# Change layout on slide up and down in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation, android-canvas

I want to implement up and down a layout that shown in attached GIF but also I want to change the layout as shown in the expected view. You can see in Google Pay app there is bezier curve layout and when we slide-up layout changes to the straight line and when to slide-down then again curve appears.

[image: Expected layout change]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have just implement Android's BottomSheetBehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using **BottomSheetBehaviour** with `CoordinatorLayout`.

Here is an example: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Docs of BottomSheetBehaviour: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior

You can change radius and translate the layout by `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback()`

Comment: Yes, but how can I change a layout?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about the "Material Backdrop" component.

You can find an implementation here:
https://github.com/Semper-Viventem/Material-backdrop?utm_source=android-arsenal.com

And here are the design guidelines:
https://material.io/components/backdrop